# Read data from a .txt file and calculate the average

Tags: python-3.x

How can I calculate the average of a .txt file with multiple columns

```
with open(ns) as np:

       next(np)
       values = np.read().splitlines()
       for line in values:
       splitline = line.split(" ")
       average = float(splitline[-4] * int(splitline[-3]) / 4
```

Comment: `splitline` is probably not what you expect it to be when you use it.  You could print that out to check if it is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.split()` to split each line on space then select values you need.

I didn't test this code but something like this should work

```
with open(name_of_share) as fp:  
   for line in fp:
     parts = line.split()
     price = float(parts[3])
     purchase = int(parts[4])
     average = float(price * purchase / 4)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. Can I also get some assistance on how to append each value to a list. I had added the line: ave_list.append(average) at the end of the code but it seems not to be working.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Thanks a lot though!